# flow chart in Windows 8 running Python 3.5.0

Tags: python, windows, flowchart

I have a flow chart problem in Windows 8 running Python 3.5.0
When I run the program there is no error message but when I type No the program executes the input as yes may you help me solve this problem.

```
print('Hello, do you want to play a game')
print('Great lets play a guessing game')
print('Think of an animal and I will ask you')
print('different questions to try to guess your animal')
print('Press Y for yes and N for no')
fly = input('Question #1 Can your animal fly?')
if fly == 'Y':
    print('You have chosen no')
bird = input('Question #2 Is your animal a bird?')
if bird == 'Y':
    print('Yay I win')
elif fly == 'N':
    print('Question #2 Can your animal swim?')
elif bird == 'N':
    print('Does your animal live on land')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty straightforward, you have written

```
if fly == 'Y':
    print('You have chosen no')
```

Obviously you meant

```
if fly == 'N':
    print('You have chosen no')
```

To find this kind of typo do not hesitate to add `print` statements in your code, or to explain your code to some rubber duck aloud, it really helps!